# Increase Headers Timeout in express

Tags: node.js, express

in order to access a Swagger UI based API I wrote some code.

```
app.get('/getData', async (req, res)=>{
    
    token = await getToken().then(res =>{return res})

    async function getData() {
        return fetch(dataurl, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accept: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.access_token
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
    }
    const result = await getData().then(res =>{return res})
    res.json(result)
})
```

The issue I have is that some requests will take about 10 minutes to finish since the data that gets accessed is very large and it just takes that time. I can't change that.

But after exactly 300 seconds I get "Headers Timeout Error" (UND_ERR_HEADERS_TIMEOUT).

I'm not sure where the 300 seconds come from. On the Swagger UI API the time is set to 600 seconds.
I think it's the standard timeout from express / NodeJS.

```
const port = 3000
const server = app.listen(port,()=>{ console.log('Server started')})
server.requestTimeout = 610000
server.headersTimeout = 610000
server.keepAliveTimeout = 600000
server.timeout = 600000
```

As you can see tried to increase all timeouts for express to about 600 seconds but nothing changes.
I also changed the network.http.response.timeout in Firefox to 600 seconds.
But still after 300 seconds I get "Headers Timeout Error".

Can anybody help me where and how I can increase the timeout for the request to go through?

Comment: probably the timeout was limited by your web server, did you check any timeout configuration on your web server?

Comment: Hi, thanks. So far I have no webserver running, just express. That's why I'm looking for a way to increase the timeout from 300 seconds to at least 600 seconds on express / NodeJS. Everything I found so far is to reduce the timeout by adding an Abort Controller but that's the opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the connect-timeout library?

```js
npm install connect-timeout
//...
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
app.use(timeout('600s'));
```

Read more here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-timeout#examples